# Minimizing the application in windows problem

Tags: java, windows

I've wrote a simple application to store some text in a derby DB. I have 2 button each one creating a new inputDialog. My problem is that when I run the program on my Ubuntu PC all is well. When I run it on a windows 7 PC when the input dialog is displayed the whole thing is minimized and hidden from the user. So each time I want some input from the user he has to restore the application. And the other problem is that the program doesn't appear in the alt-tab menu too. Here is the code that I use to display the dialog:

```
String s = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Моля въведете име:");
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, is this line called from within the window, i.e. in the JPanel/JFrame/etc. class?

Comment: Yes it is called from a JFrame which is the one and only frame in this app and it gets minimized too :).

Comment: Try the code I provided and let us know what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code - directly from main() via eclipse running on Windows 7 64-bit. The JFrame remains on display, even if I try otherwise.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(750, 500);
f.show();

JOptionPane.showInputDialog(f, "hello", "there");
System.out.println("hi");
```

Try this, and if you get the same result then at least we know it's a windows issue that we're dealing with rather than a Java issue.

**EDIT:**

After looking through your code, I found the offending line. Also as a side note, you should generally call `setVisible()` *after* you have done configuring your window. This is especially true with my code, as it would throw an exception if you try to call `setUndecorated()` *after* you have displayed the window.

Your Code:

```
this.setVisible(true);           //This should be called after you finish configuration
device.setFullScreenWindow(this); //This is the problem!!!
```

Instead you should use:

```
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
this.setVisible(true);
```

If you want to have your window fullscreen then use:

```
this.setUndecorated(true);
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
this.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Well this works OK. I even added a button to call this code and it works OK.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting (and typical). Were you able to tell why that is? It would help if you posts it ore code, such as your initialization of the JFrame

Comment: @mitakis2002: I have found the problem! See the answer above.